# `python3` define a function when `list[True, True, True]`, return `False` when there exist `False` in the list

Tags: python-3.x

Define a function that returns:

- `True`, when all the elements in the list are `True`,
- `False`, when there is one or more than one `False` in the list,
- `False`, when the list is empty.

```py
def all(n):
   for True in n:
       if not True:
            return False
        return True
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The code you wrote was *almost* right. Be careful: `True` and `False` are keywords, so you may not use them as variable names. You should write instead `for x in n`.
Also, is that a programming exercise? This is how you should ask questions related to homework: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Eric you don't need to define an explicit function for your case, python already has a builtin function for it. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def all(n):
    if not n:
        # For empty list
        return False

    for i in n:
        if not i:
            return False
    return True

print(all([True, True, True]))
print(all([True, False, True]))
print(all([]))
```

Prints:

```
True
False
False
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, we already have https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Answer (score 1):

We already have a function for this [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), we can use it along with a special condition for empty list, since `all([])` gives True.
`if lst` is False for empty list, otherwise it is True

```
def func(lst):
   result = all(lst) if lst else False
   return result

print(func([True, True, True]))
print(func([True, False, True]))
print(func([]))
#True
#False
#False
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function syntax shows its beauty:

```
f = lambda x: False if not(x) else all(x)

print(f([True, True, True]))
print(f([True, False, True]))
print(f([]))
```

and you get:

```
True
False
False
```